# Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:

Tags: apache, ssl, tomcat7

I have Installed apache, Tomcat7 on a server, my requests are redirecting from apache to tomcat.
I have installed a SSL on apache. I am using goole api's for some authentication in my app.
But i am getting following error

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:

Wht will be the solution to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The certificate of the target application is not trusted by the source application because the certificate or chain of certificates cannot be found in the source application's JVM truststore.

Make sure you have imported your certificates into the truststore.

Check to see that the correct truststore is in use.

refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562523/com-iplanet-services-comm-client-sendrequestexception-sun-security-validator-va) more info.